# Functions to be run only when server is started

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a Rails application. I want to execute a piece of code only during
server start-up. Where do I add this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `config/initializers`. All the `.rb` files in that directory will only be run when the server is started.